# Proper inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, terminology

What is meant by proper inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to add to what Justin and Baxter said.

The term proper inheritance is not really well-defined. Properly using inheritance is quite a subjective issue...

Consider the following example:

- An interface: `Bird`
- A concrete class: `Ostrich`

Should `Ostrich` inherits from `Bird` ? From a zoological point of view it makes sense, but from a Computer Science point of view... not so much. If `Bird` has a `fly` method, then how am I supposed to handle this in `Ostrich::fly` :x ?

There is somewhat of a war in the CS community. Indeed you'll regularly see books where `Circle` inherits from `Ellipse` (or the other way around) when it doesn't really makes sense from a CS point of view.

So my own little definition:

> Considering that the interface defines precise semantics for each of its methods, a concrete class should only inherit from the interface if the implementation of each of the method matches the semantics specified.

Answer (score 4):

[This thread](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/42946) gives a nice summary:

> - Proper inheritance occurs when the derived class "IS A" specialized type of the base class. Example Cat IS A Animal.
> - Improper inheritance occurs when a class is inherited from merely for code reuse without having any other relationship. Example Cat Inherits from Engine. A Cat is not an engine however both an engine and a cat purr.

Comment: I had checked it out but the example seemed weird.

Comment: A _nice_ summary?  I second ckv's opinon... Truly, if this concept of inheritance propriety is effectively useful there must exist better sources which define, summarize and provide insight into it...

Comment: I meant the text I quoted is a nice summary :) - I agree with you there must exist better sources. It seems the problem here is that there is no official term "Proper Inheritance" just that if you are using inheritance correctly, you will be expressing an IS-A relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps first we should recall what the value of inheritance itself is. Inheritance is a mechanism for both code reuse and interface reuse (polymorphism).  But you can have code reuse without inheritance by using composition and delegation. And in many languages you can have polymorphism without inheritance, but not all languages.  In a strongly typed language such as C++, polymorphism, which is itself another important code reuse mechanism, can only be achieved using inheritance.  In fact, C++ distinguishes between public and private inheritance for interface and code reuse respectively.  More on this later.

Generally one thinks of a class's methods as creating a contract with clients of the class: It guarantees that as long as you call a method having met certain preconditions, the method will deliver certain results.  "Proper" inheritance is such that the subclass instance can be substituted for its parent class without violating the parent's contract.  That is, none of the subclass's methods should override its base class's methods requiring stricter preconditions nor delivering more "less" results.  Returning to C++, since there is a clear distinction between public and private  inheritance where the former is required so that you may substitute a subclass instance for a base class instance, it is generally considered "proper" that the substitution be semantically correct. Otherwise why not use private inheritance?

Is `Ostrich` a valid subclass of `Bird`?  It depends on what your abstraction of `Bird` is?  If the `Bird` class has a method `Bird::fly` that does something tangible but `Ostrich::fly` overrides this to throw an exception and thus delivers "less" than its base class, I would say no.  But if class `Bird` did not have a `fly` method (there is another subclass `Flying_Bird` that does), no problem.

My answer is that what holds for C++ is not a bad guideline for any object-oriented language. In a languages like Python where an inheritance hierarchy is not required for polymorphism, people might have a greater tendency to use inheritance just for code reuse. If this reuse is well-documented, it might not be an issue. But **when I see a class hierarchy, my expectation is that a subclass is potentially going to be used polymorphically and thus an instance of the subclass can be substituted for an instance of the base class thereby obeyeing the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) where a subclass is also a *subtype*.**

Answer (score 0):

When inheritance complies with a IS A relationship, as opposed to inheriting purely for code reuse without there being a logical subsumption of the child by the superclass.